# input pattern detect start diget

Tags: php, input

how to set input pattern for  : if start with 4 then length is 16 digets if starts with 6 then length is 17 digets

for example:

when input starts with 6 then it must be:  pattern="\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{1}"

But when input starts with 4 it must be: pattern="\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{4}"

how to set pattern??